# Limit the no of files to read while polling for new files using AvroIO apache beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am attempting to create a PCollection of generic records by using AvroIO to read Avro files from a specified GCS location using a specific pattern and process it. I have set the polling interval and have defined the termination condition. This setup works well for small loads. However, when the load increases, I notice some discrepancies in the count of input being read.

Below is my sample code

```
var genericRecords: PCollection<GenericRecord>= pipeline.apply(AvroI0.readGenericRecords (schema). from (options.inputfilePattern) .withEmptyMatchTreatment (EmptyHatchTreatment.ALLOW).watchForNewFiles (Duration.standardMinutes(options.pollDuration), Watch.Growth.afterTimeSinceNewOutput (Duration.standardiinutes(jobTerminationDuration))))
```

I am wondering if there is a way to limit the number of files I can read on each polling cycle. For example, if I retrieve 200 files on my first poll, is there a way to pause the polling until these files are processed?

Thank you for your time.

Tried using FiloIo but no luck